# Заметил ошибку особенность в предосмотре правки

Tags: дефект, предложение, статус-так-задумано, правки

Я недавно [редактировал сообщение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/280370) и заметил интересное различие, способное запутать экспертов при принятии правки.

Итак:

**Обычный предосмотр:**

[image]

Никаких переносов на следующую строку

**Разметка markdown**

[image]

Тоесть сложно будет определить так налету как оно написано(с пропуском или без).

**Зачем??**

***(Моё предложение)***

*Сделать как-то стандартнее хотябы не путать модераторов.*

Comment: Что неправильно-то? markdown позволяет добавлять переносы, которые не становятся переносами после рендера. Для удобства чтения исходников. Проблема-то в чём?

Comment: тоже не вижу проблем

Comment: Перенос строки разве нужен

Comment: @PowerToYou нет, не нужен. Но вы же его сами поставили!

Comment: Меня больше diff третьего пункта смущает. А в чём заключается описываемая проблема, я так и не понял.

Comment: @vp_arth предлагаю написать ответ, а после флагнуть мода для установки [так-задумано].

Comment: @vp_arth, я вообще не понимаю вопрос, так что статус проверить не могу и метку добавлять не буду...

Comment: @PowerToYou, вам разве недоступна опция удалить его?

Comment: @Qwertiy читайте ответ, там всё написано

Comment: @alexolut, на нём нет галочки...

Comment: @Qwertiy это когда-то было причиной? Галочка исключительно для автора.

Comment: @alexolut, отсутствие галочки в данном случае для меня означает, что трактовка вопроса отвечающим может отличаться от авторского смысла, который я не понимаю из вопроса.

Answer (score 5):

В этом нет никакой проблемы.

`markdown` позволяет добавлять переносы, которые не становятся переносами после рендера. Для удобства чтения исходников.

Для принятия решения о качестве правки, участникам предоставляется возможность увидеть оба варианта: исходный markdown, и отрендеренный контент.